# Using tuples in a Heap for multidimensional sorting?

Tags: python, algorithm, heapsort

Say I have a list such as:

```
[(3,4), (4,3), (1,5), (5,1), (2,6), (6,2)]
```

where I want to return the tuple with the lowest x-value, and also one with the lowest y-value.

Is it possible to build a (min-)heap using index 0, and a different heap using index 1? That would make two heaps:

```
for x: [(1,5), (2,6), (3,4), (4,3), (5,1), (6,2)]
#and
for y: [(5,1), (6,2), (4,3), (3,4), (1,5), (2,6)].
```

Can we use heapsort for tuples?

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to efficiently answer two different queries ("Which tuple has the lowest x value?" and "Which tuple has the lowest y value?")?

Comment: Oops sorry, I meant to say two different return values: one that returns (1,5), and one that returns (5,1). So yes to @j_random_hacker.

Comment: If you don't really have to use a heap, try `sorted(a,key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=False)[0]`. Change the key and reverse to your liking.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python, so I couldn't tell you how to achieve this, but in principle heaps can work with any datatype that obeys a total order (in practice: a comparison function f(x, y) that always consistently return "true" or "false" so that e.g. f(x, y) and f(y, z) implies f(x, z) for any 3 elements x, y and z). Ordering pairs of integers by their second element is certainly a total order, so I'm sure Python provides a way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is yes, you can use [heapsort](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#basic-examples) on tuples:

> Heap elements can be tuples. This is useful for assigning comparison values (such as task priorities) alongside the main record being tracked...

However it is also [mentioned in the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) that:

> [nsmallest and nlargest] perform best for smaller values of n. For larger values, it is more efficient to use the sorted() function. Also, when n==1, it is more efficient to use the built-in min() and max() functions.

That is, if you want the minimum y, use [`min`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min):

```
tuple_list = [(3,4), (4,3), (1,5), (5,1), (2,6), (6,2)]

min(tuple_list, key=lambda x: x[1])
# (5,1)
```

and if you want to sort the entire list, use [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
sorted(tuple_list, key=lambda x: x[1])
# [(5,1), (6,2), (4,3), (3,4), (1,5), (2,6)]
```

Whereas if you want to use the three smallest values, use [`heapq.nsmallest`](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest):

```
heapq.nsmallest(3, tuple_list, key=lambda x: x[1])
# [(5,1), (6,2), (4,3)]
```